# String index out of range - java

Tags: java

What does that mean? The length of the string is too long or there is error in my code?

```
  public class Program {
        public static String flipEndChars(String s) {
            if(s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(s.length())){
                return "Two's a pair.";
            }
            else if(s.length()<3){
                return "incompatible";
            }
            else 
                return s.charAt(s.length()) + s.substring(1,s.length()) + s.charAt(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The maximum index is  s.length() - 1

Comment: no, it means that if your String has x characters, you are trying to get the x + 1'th (or more) character of the String. Like trying to get the fourth char of "get"

Comment: `s.charAt(s.length())` will ALWAYS fail. `s.charAt(0)` will fail when `s` is empty.

Comment: Indexes start from 0, not 1. So index of n-th element will be n-1. So if there are M elements last index will be M-1.

Comment: also maybe you want to check for s.length()<3 first, otherwise you are missing this validation when the String's first and last characters match

Answer (score 0):

the issue is with this part :

```
s.charAt(s.length())
```

It's trying to access a character beyond the length of your string. The indexation is zero based, so the last character of a string is always at index `s.length() - 1`

Answer (score 0):

`String.charAt(int)` returns the char at the specified index, where 0 is the first character, 1 is the second character, 2 is the third, and so on.

`"hello".charAt(0)` returns the character `h`.

`String.length()` returns the length of the string.
`"hello".length()` returns `5`. So if you call `"hello.charAt(5)"`, this will get the 6th character in the String "hello", which does not exist. This will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I hope this helps.